# Is there a way to lock a particular instance of vs code while working with multiple instances?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are times when one is working with multiple instances of vs-code... In that situation, It becomes soo easy to put code in wrong instance... Is there any way to lock a particular vs-code instance while working with multiple instances.

This question is more of a suggestion for vs-code developers to add this feature

Comment: If you're on Windows 10, you could move the window you're not working with to another Virtual Desktop. Another solution would be, you can save that VSCode window as a workspace which saves your open tabs etc. to a file, close the window then when you need it, open that file.

Comment: @Shayan The matter is that i am working with all the windows at the same time... but editing only one... I am having only one screen of dimensions 1366x768... My question was kindof a suggestion for the vs-code developers to implement this feature

Answer (score 3):

With the extension [When File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.WhenFile) you can color your VSC instances differently depending on the workspace it has open.

Or you can create a Multi Root Workspace and have all your workspaces open in one VSC instance